# Feeding an antenna with DC or AC

Tags: ac, dc, antenna, oscillator, signal

Below is a picture with what I have done so far. It gives me a square wave with a voltage between -2.5 V and 2.5 V.

Is this enough to feed an antenna so that it works? Would feeding the antenna with this signal be enough to excite the antenna properly? Do I need a sine wave instead?

[image: schematic]

Comment: All i got from a CMOS inverter crystal oscillator was a square wave. Is that enough to feed the antenna with given AC current ?

Comment: It isn't even clear that you're asking a question.  You need to _edit your question_.  Narrow it down to _one specific thing_.  Tell us _what you're trying to accomplish_ at a top level (it sounds like you want to make a radio transmitter).  Perhaps post _just one schematic_ and ask why it might or might not work.  N.b.: no, you cannot just feed DC to an antenna and have anything work.  Antennas couple fairly narrow-band AC signals to the world; they really do anything useful with DC.

Comment: Above i sent a picture about what have done so far. It gives me a square wave with a voltage between -2.5V and 2.5V. Is that enough to feed the antenna so that it works.

Comment: You need to _edit your question_ until it is clear what you are asking.  Why don't you _edit your question_ by _deleting all of the extraneous words_, then _copy your comment above into the question_.  Then your question will be clear, concise, and above all, answerable.

Comment: You're new to Stackexchange -- please note that if you _edit your question_ so that it has sufficient clarity, it will very likely get reopened.

Comment: You want to know if it "works", but what is it "work"-ing to do? Are you trying to transmit to something? Do you have a receiver somewhere else? What kind of antenna is it? What kind of filtering does it provide? (Transmitters must not emit harmonics: a square wave is 48% harmonics, so the schematic shown is a poor start!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An antenna won't 'do' anything unless it is fed a time-varying (AC) signal. It could be a single step of DC, which will produce a pulse on the antenna. The very first antennas worked exactly like that: 'spark gap' transmitters emitted an electromagnetic pulse when a spark jumped between two charged points.

More here: https://www.instructables.com/Spark-Gap-TransmitterMarconi-Receiver-the-Simplest/

A continuous-wave transmitter can use an oscillator. What you show will be a *square wave* parallel oscillator, which will make a fundamental frequency set by the crystal along with a lot of sideband harmonics. Not ideal, but for just playing around at low power, not much of a problem (note: could cause interference with other stuff - if this happens, stop.) An improvement would be to make a sinewave oscillator to make a purer signal.

But, if you attach a piece of wire to the buffer at right you'll get something.

Now what about the antenna? Practically anything can be an 'antenna', including just a piece of wire. The magic is in designing an antenna that transfers the input (excitation) energy to electromagnetic waves as efficiently as possible.

A properly-matched antenna appears to the driver as a known impedance (e.g. 50 ohms) at its input port. When an antenna is working at its best, all of the energy fed into the input port makes its way out as electromagnetic radiation (that is, RF signal), and none of it is reflected back to the driver. There are various terms for this, a common one is 'standing wave ratio', or SWR.

Back to your project. You probably don't care yet about refining your antenna at this point, you just want to see if things are working. One way is to use a *field strength meter*. For low-ish frequencies (like CB radio, around 27MHz) these are very cheap.

Another way, if you have access to an oscilloscope you can fashion a loop antenna with a piece of wire and connect your probe to that.

Comment: I agree with you and would like to upvote your answer. I don't have 15 reputations. Guys are very hard on these days. They downvote anything that is hard to understand for a beginner.  Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: Delete your own answer, and if you wish make it as a comment on your question.

Comment: Oscillation is the basic idea, how things are being transferred from antenna to antenna. Antennas are working with oscillators. For example, crystal oscillators. Whatever the input signal will be, the oscillator will trigger the antenna by that ratio frequency which is given. Therefore, the input signal can be anything that goes up to antenna. Only a crystal in circuit does nothing. It depends on input signal which flows through it. This signal will excite the antenna in the frequency of the crystal.